# Check for directive has an value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to show text on the basis of the directive i.e. if directive has some value then prints it otherwise show or hide div. E.g

```
<out name={{users}}></out>
```

If above directive return something then show/hide the below div

```
<div ng-show="something to check that above directive returns value or not">abc</div>
```

Vinod

Answer (score 0):

Based on the value your directive has via the name attribute, you can check if users has a value using the [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive:

```
<out name={{users}}></out>

<!-- check we have users (assuming it's an array of users) -->
<div ng-show="users && users.length">abc</div>
```

Comment: It always has users. But depending on some condition it is returning values. So sometimes it will return empty and on other times it wil return some value

Comment: `directive(
    'out',
    function() {
     return function(scope, element, attr) {
      element
        .text(scope.objectives[scope.objectives.length - 1].out);
     }
    })`